# "Object Required" error when calling javascript from a jsp in IE7

Tags: javascript, jsp, object, required

I am getting a very odd error that I can't seem to get rid of in my code.  At the bottom of my jsp I have the following code snippit:

```
<jsp:include page="YuiCalendar.jsp" />
<script>
YAHOO.vgi.popcal.calendar.init();
alert(YAHOO.vgi.popcal.calendar.init);
</script>
```

The first call to init is throwing the "Object Required" error, at first I thought I may be calling it incorrectly, but the alert statement correctly returns and shows the method from YuiCalendar, but adding the '()' causes the error to be thrown, the init method has no input paramenters.  What makes this problem even odder is I have the exact same few lines of code in another .jsp, and that works fine.  All the .jsp files are in the same folder as well.

Comment: The error may be happening somewhere inside the function. IE7 is not very good about accurate error locations.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pointy, you were correct, there was an error in the function that was being caused by a missing tag in the .jsp itself.